# Is it possible to put an if else statement inside an if else statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

So basically, what I want to do is to use "if / else" as switches for program to choose a path.

I want more indented if / else NOT to work, if my elif statement was false. Is it possible?

Code:

```
aStr = "abcdef"
char = "e"
if aStr == '':
    return False
elif len(aStr) == 1:
    if char == aStr:
        return True
    else:
        print "Python is stupid"
        return False
else:
```

And it returns "Python is stupid", which I don't meant it to do!

Comment: What is in the final `else` clause?  It seems to me that should be the branch your program takes...

Comment: are you sure this program doesn't do what you think it does? (that is to say, this code does what you want it to do, and not what you claim it does)

Comment: given the aStr you are providing in your sample code, your result should flow to the outer 'else' statement.

Comment: I agree with monkut. This appears to be a function definition with some values tacked on at the top. Could you provide the rest of the definition, including the signature and whatever is in the last else clause? From you comment on the answer below and from reading what your code does, I suspect you're using recursion, and perhaps we could be more helpful if we better understood the control flow. Also, Python is not stupid. It's quite a nice language with tons of very convenient and useful features.

Comment: The code you posted is a SyntaxError (You can't have `return` outside a function. You also can't have the dangling `else`). If it's supposed to be inside a function, why can't you put it inside one? Why not show what's in the final `else:` block since that's what looks like it should be executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to run when it's not true, you need to reverse your logic in the `elif`:

```
aStr = "abcdef"
char = "e"
if aStr == '':
    return False
elif len(aStr) != 1:
    if char == aStr:
        return True
    else:
        print "Python is stupid"
        return False
```

The `if` (and by extension, `elif`) statement runs the block if the given expression is true. If you want to check if something *isn't* true, you reverse the logic (putting a `not` in front of it, or using the inverse operator).

Note that the Pythonic way to check for an empty string is to do `if not aStr:`, rather than check for equality vs an empty string.

Comment: Thx for trying to help. The problem is, it's not the logic that I wanted.

The thing is, I gotta do bisection search to find or not find them character. I guess, I'll just have to use function inside a function BS.

Comment: That's the logic you asked for. You need to clarify what you want.